# Wiring 2 prong outlet to 3 prong outlet

Tags: receptacle, grounding

hi so i brought a old house and some of the rooms have 2 prong outlet with only hot/neutral wire and i changed the 2 prong outlet to a gfci 3 prong outlet but it doesnt have a ground. My question is can i pigtail the ground to a existing 3 prong outlet that have a ground wire to it.

Answer (score 4):

If the ground comes from the same service panel you can tap into that ground and it will be code compliant with the 2017 NEC , if it comes from a different source the code compliant method is to attach a sticker that comes with the GFCI , GFCI protected no equipment ground.

Comment: Here are a couple pages that go into the details of Ed's answer https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=306.0 , https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=52.0

Comment: here is what im thinkiing to do let me know which way is the safest or none of them is safe https://ibb.co/rFzDvQD

Comment: I am not sure I follow the drawing it shows multiple GFCI’s on the same chain, if each GFCI is fed from the line of the unit prior there will be no issues but if the secondary GFCI’s are fed from the load you may have tripping problems but the ground appears to be ok.

Comment: i am reusing the power and neutral wire from the 2 prong outlet on the gfci im just running a ground wire and pigtail it to each gfci outlet so it have ground wire to it.